# error installing laravel via composer on new pc

Tags: php, laravel

I have a new laptop and I'm trying to install Laravel via composer.
I usually use PhpStorm wizard to create new projects.

For some reason it keeps failing to install Laravel on my new device, I've installed `PHP` via wamp and `git` and `composer`.

I've no idea what is wrong.

[image]

Here is my PHP & git

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with this phpstorm wizard, but my hunch is you arent passing it the parameters correctly based on the error message. It is looking for ```www\untitled1\composer/vendor``` and in the wizard command you are passing ```create-project laravel\laravel composer```

Comment: The `--no-install` flag will prevent `composer install` from being called. Not sure why PhpStorm is using it, but it shouldn't

Comment: Don't post images of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is remove your composer directory and run composer install again.
I saw that your autoload failed to load which can cause this issue.

This is probably because you changed the directories.

Comment: you mean i should remove the directory which composer is installed in ? wouldn't that make composer terminal commands undefined ?

Comment: @hretic You should remove the /composer/ folder to reinstall it using your composer.json, then just run composer install in the directory of your composer.json